# error: cannot install "heroku": snap not found

Tags: heroku, ubuntu-14.04

I am following the instructions from official heroku website to install heroku on my ubuntu 14.04.

First I installed **snapd** on ubuntu and then tried to install heroku by running:

`sudo snap install heroku`

But I am getting following error

`error: cannot install "heroku": snap not found`

I posted this question on askubuntu but it wasn't of much help. Could somebody please help how can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

To install heroku in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

This installs the heroku snap package successfully, and it is the recommended way of installing Heroku CLI in Ubuntu at the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) website. When this was posted `sudo snap install --classic heroku` installs the latest version of Heroku.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now. I just did a `snap install heroku --classic` on a 14.04 system and it installs and works fine.